# web links in help menu not working

Tags: interface, linux

Nothing in the "help" menu seems to work when it points to a web address.

At the top of the blender there is a list of actions (File, Render, Window, Help)
when I click on the "Help" button I get a selection of options to pick, I am too new to know what "Python API Reference","Operator Cheat Sheet", "Save system Info", is supposed to do, but I do know the other options have a reference to web sites, when I click them nothing happens. Clicking the web links in the Splash screen works ok.

Ubuntu has decided to use the "SNAP" system to install this program, it looks like I have a few disconnects with this type of installation.

Blender (2.78c)

UBUNTU 16.10
(old system)
Gigabyte main board
AMD athlan IIx2 240 Processor
8 gig
gtx-750 TI

Comment: Could you please clarify exactly what is not working, it is not very clear what you mean

Comment: Download blender from here: https://www.blender.org/download/, then everything will work.

Comment: Thanks @brockmann I did that originally and the system worked great , but I was unable to get the update to the program without removing and re-installing it. I read about the "SNAP" system and decided to try it, Blender is the only program in the "Snap" system. I do thank you for the answer.